# c# passing Parameters values from function to other function

Tags: c#, function, parameters, parameter-passing

are there any way to get the values from Parameters in  "functionone" and calculate it in the "functiontwo" without writing that again that's a small code for example what i mean

```
public void functionone(int x, int y)
{

   x = 1;
   y = 2;

}

public void functiontwo(int a , int b )
{
   a=x+y;
   b=x-y;

   Console.WriteLine(a);
   Console.WriteLine(b);


}
```

Comment: No, you must call it explicitly.

Comment: No, you should call functiontwo from functionOne and pass the parameter.

Comment: @NeerajSharma how i call it ?

Comment: functiontwo(x,y), set there values as globally. as one of mention in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implementing functionone wrongly I guess
doing this:
    public void functionone(int x, int y)
    {
       x = 1;
       y = 2;
    }
is normally not the way to pass parameters and change its values in the method,
or saying in another way, x and y should be holding the values you pass as parameters, and no getting assigned inside the method..

define a global x and global y, then you can access to it everywhere in that scope..

## Example:

```
class Abc{
    int globalX;
    int globalY;
....
public void functionone(int x, int y)
{
   globalX = 1 + x;
   globalY = 2 + y;
}

public void functiontwo(int a , int b )
{
   a=globalX + globalY;
   b=globalX - globalY;

   Console.WriteLine(a);
   Console.WriteLine(b);
}

}
```

Comment: Note: You can use `ref` keyword to pass variables, so the value is retained after method call. `functionone` should get the variables to set 1 and 2 to them, you're passing x's value, not the variable.

Answer (score 0):

To explain my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190390/c-sharp-passing-parameters-values-from-function-to-other-function#comment65721760_39190417):

```
int globalX;
int globalY;

public void functionone(ref int x, ref int y)
{
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
}

public void functiontwo(ref int a , ref int b)
{
    a = globalX + globalY;
    b = globalX - globalY;

    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}


// in main

functionone(ref globalX, ref globalY);
// globalX and globalY are now 1 and 2

functiontwo(ref a, ref b);
// a = 3 and b = -1  ->  'globalX +/- globalY'
```

This way you can set the values of any variables you pass to `functionone` or `functiontwo`.

However it doesn't look good and in my opinion it's not a good code. Your concept seems wrong, so maybe you can post a description of the problem you encountered?